# Restrict a search to a custom post type

Tags: templates, search

I have a search form in the home page and search form in the sidebar. Is it possible to make the search form in the home page show results as per a specific template and make the sidebar search form show a different template?

i want to make the homepage search box to show results in different way. Its a custom post. so if user uses that form it should only have data from that custom post. But the default wordpress search box in the sidebar should get the results from entire website.

eg. listing search page results with map

Thanks

Comment: As in, if you search from the home page, the page you're displaying results on is different from the one in the sidebar?

Comment: Now they both have the same template

Comment: Do the search forms actually search for anything different? What's the difference, if any, between the forms?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes one search is for a custom post and another for default one.

Comment: And what are the requests sent by these forms? Can you tell which is which based on GET params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict a search to a custom post type by modifying a basic WP search form like this:

```
<form id="cptsearch" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="POSTTYPENAME" />
    <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

To select a specialized template for the custom post type search, add this filter in your functions file:

```
function template_chooser($template) {
    global $wp_query;
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'POSTTYPENAME' ) {
    return locate_template('page_POSTTYPENAME.php');
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

And of course, you must create the specialized search results template: page_POSTTYPENAME.php

Comment: Hello, thanks  but it seems the index.php is getting loaded instead template "page_POSTTYPENAME & there is no search results when in am using the form.

Comment: You're inserting the actual post type name for POSTTYPENAME in all cases?

Comment: Yes, i have changed  all the POSTTYPENAME to my custom post type name

Comment: What is your post type name?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Hello my post type is "l" , it's the same code above will all POSTTYPENAME replaced

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: For both the search form and template chooser filter?

Comment: <form id="cptsearch" action="/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="l" value="l" />
    <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>

Comment: function template_chooser($template) {
    global $wp_query;
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'l' ) {
    return locate_template('page_l.php');
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');

Comment: Not spotting anything that should be an issue. One more 'is your computer plugged in' kind of question: You created page_l.php with appropriate code to display the custom post type search results?

Comment: Yes. But it's not detecting the template file.

Comment: My mistake: try using this for hidden field in search form:
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="l" />

Comment: Works fine. Really appreciate your help .thank you :)

Comment: Hello Ray Just having a small issue with the form ..it works fine when i am using it on some hosting service but when i am using a local host it stops working as i have to change the action to "/wordpress/ any fix for this?

Comment: You're looking at the difference between how your localhost and webhost handle pathways; sorry, but I don't have expertise in this area, and can't advise you on how to avoid the need to make this minor edit between the two environments.

Comment: Hello Ray..it's okay i have posted as new question may be someone can help me with that : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316635/custom-search-form-not-working-in-localhost

Comment: Try substituting this:

Comment: for action, between php brackets: echo home_url();

Comment: If that works for you, please let me know.

Comment: Hey thanks it works for both localhost and webhost :)