# Custom Search form not working in localhost

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, search

This was the solution that i got from @Ray Gulick for having a custom search form for custom post type. This works fine in hosting service but fails in localhost as the form action is added as  `action="/"` if i change it to `action="/localhostprojectname/"` then it works .

Any workaround to fix this?

---

You can restrict a search to a custom post type by modifying a basic WP search form like this:

```
<form id="cptsearch" action="/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="POSTTYPENAME" />
    <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

To select a specialized template for the custom post type search, add this filter in your functions file:

```
function template_chooser($template) {
    global $wp_query;
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'POSTTYPENAME' ) {
    return locate_template('page_POSTTYPENAME.php');
    }
    return $template;
}

add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

And of course, you must create the specialized search results template: page_POSTTYPENAME.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has to updated as

```
 <form id="cptsearch" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="s" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="POSTTYPENAME" />
        <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
    </form>
```